# How to Stop a callback function at the first true result of a deep iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am am working on an App for yoga classes.

**[EDITED]**

I have eddited my `state` in order to better exemplify my question. On all the answers received the result will stop upon the first existing element in `this.state.existingElements`. Now I have added another `instance` to the `array` of `objects`(`this.state.existingElements`) to make it clear that the iteration should `setState` just once per existing element. My own answer below still gets the desired result, but I think that is not optimal.

**[/EDITED]**

...........=>

Just to contextualize the deal here:

Whenever an instructor wants to create a new class I have set a `function` that will get the starting date, hour & minute of the new class, calculate the ending time of the class, according to the duration set by the instructor, then creates an object that has, at one of its instances, an array that elapses each minute of the class, from start to end, in milliseconds.

Then the object of this discussion gets in scene:

I want to compare the elapse of each class, to determine if the new class will conflict with any existing one, previously set.

I have come with this piece of code, but I am having trouble at the end of the logic.

when I do this statement `if (existingElement.elapse.includes(newFraction))` I would like it to stop iterating on the first `true` return, so I do not `"push"` the same existing conflicting class more then once to `this.state. conflictingClasses`.

I have tried other formats... I've tried using `some()`, tried replacing `if (existingElement.elapse.includes(newFraction))` for another `.forEach()` deeper iteration, so I would compare each instance of each `array`, moving the `if` statement deeper, into this deeper `forEach()`.

I have finally tried using a `while(!this.sate.conflictingClasses.includes(existingElement))` before running `setState`, and this last attempt froze the app haha.

I understand that I could manipulate `this.state.conflictingClasses` as a `callback` of `this.setState`, to avoid the duplicity issue, but this would still make the logic iterate more then necessary.

I hope I made myself clear: I would like this iteration to stop when `newFraction` is found the first time in `existingElement.elapse` so I do the `setState` just once per `existingElement`

I will post the code below and [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/admiring-river-tce0p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    conflictingClasses: [],//in this case it should get id 2 & id 3 in here
    existingElements: [
      { id: 1, elapse: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
      { id: 2, elapse: [5, 6, 7, 8] },
      { id: 3, elapse: [9, 10, 11, 12] }
    ],
    newElements: [
      { id: 3, elapse: [8, 9, 10, 11] },
      { id: 4, elapse: [13, 14, 15, 99] }
    ]
  };

  newElementsValidatorHandler = () => {
    this.state.existingElements.forEach(existingElement => {
      return this.state.newElements.forEach(newElement =>
        newElement.elapse.some(newFraction => {
          if (existingElement.elapse.includes(newFraction)) {
            this.setState(({ conflictingClasses, ...restTop }) => ({
              conflictingClasses: [
                ...conflictingClasses.filter(
                  prevClasses => prevClasses !== existingElement
                ),
                existingElement
              ],
              ...restTop
            }));
          }
        })
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <button onClick={this.newElementsValidatorHandler}>Run Tests!</button>
        <h2>Display Conflicting elements: </h2>
        {this.state.conflictingClasses.map(conflictingClass => (
          <p key={conflictingClass.id}>Conflicting Id: {conflictingClass.id}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to avoid pushing to the state one `existingElement` for each time a conflicting `fraction` is found:

I used dummy helper variables in order to avoid repeating myself on this block.

The key to avoid unnecessary iterations comes in here:

```
for (let i = 0; !conflictingClasses.includes(existingElement); i++) {
         conflictingClasses.push(existingElement);
            }
```

So I am telling `javascript`, hey, just push instances while they do not exist in my dummy `array`.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/testing-iteration-in-between-two-arrays-tce0p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) updated.

```
aForSolutionHandler = () => {
    const existinElements = [...this.state.existingElements];
    const newElements = [...this.state.newElements];
    let conflictingClasses = [];
    //here I loop in the existing elements array
    for (let existingElement of existinElements) {
      //here I loop in the new elements array
      for (let newElement of newElements) {
        //here I iterate each value of elapse of each new element
        newElement.elapse.some(newFraction => {
          //if any fraction is found in any value of elapse of existing elements return true
          if (existingElement.elapse.includes(newFraction)) {
            //here I limit the number of iterations to expose the conflicting elements only once per element, to avoid the issue, object of our discussion
            for (
              let i = 0;
              !conflictingClasses.includes(existingElement);
              i++
            ) {
              conflictingClasses.push(existingElement);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
   //now I use the dummy array to send it to my state
    this.setState({ conflictingClasses });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution but it reorganizes your function quite a bit. I would be open to any suggestions by others on how to improve this.

First, I removed all the calls to `map`. Map will iterate over an array but it also returns a new version of the array.

Second, I flattened all the new elements into a single array. This way, you can compare times within existing elements to the whole of the new at once.

[EDITED]

Third, and finally, you can simply `filter` the existing results in the callback function to `setState` and return only the existingElements that include a value from the newElementsValueArray.

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-iteration-in-between-two-arrays-f4g6h)

```
newElementsValidatorHandler = () => {
    // reduce the newElements array into an array of just the elapse values
    const newElements = this.state.newElements.reduce((arr, {elapse}) => {
      return [...arr, ...elapse];
    }, []);

    // add filtered existing elements to setState callback
    this.setState(({ conflictingClasses, ...restTop }) => ({
      conflictingClasses: [
      ...conflictingClasses,
      ...this.state.existingElements.filter(({elapse}) =>
        elapse.some(el => newElements.includes(el))
      )
    ],
    ...restTop
  }));
}
```

Comment: Oh I see!! It does not matter which element the conflict occurs, regarding the new elements being brought, so I see that the key of your approach is to get all the values of each ```elapse``` property array into one unique array. Thanks for shedding some light here! I had not seen this logic approach

Comment: No Problem. I also just edited my response to simplify it. See how I use the filter function within `setState`, to only return elements that include values in both new and existing elapse arrays.

Comment: @Alioshr I simplified my answer quite a bit. See above.

Comment: Very slick and short! Thanks so much for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

> I would like this iteration to stop when newFraction is found the
>   first time in existingElement.elapse so I do the setState just once
>   per existingElement

It's true you cant pre-emptively abort .forEach and .map because returning would only return from current callback invocation without cancelling the rest

First thing I'd like to point out is the misuse of `.map` - this function is used to "transform" one array into another - that is, to produce a new array. You are using `.map` as if it is a `.forEach` here

If you want to be able to break or return inside iteration, use `for` or `for .. of` loop. These don't receive callbacks and don't create new function scope inside of them

While you could use things like [labeled breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (after convertion .forEach to for), and point out to exact loop you want to break from, this would still be very uncommon and error prone pattern. What you want to do is to extract your code in separate logical functions and construct your iteration from them:

```
newElementsValidatorHandler = () => {
  this.state.existingElements.forEach(existingElement => {
    if (existingElementIncludesNewFraction(existingElement)) {
      this.setState(({ conflictingClasses }) => ({
        conflictingClasses: [...conflictingClasses, existingElement]
      }))
    }
  })
}


existingElementIncludesNewFraction = (existingElement) => {
  for (const newElement of this.state.newElements) {
    for (const newFraction of newElement.elapse) {
      if (existingElement.elapse.includes(newFraction)) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that would give you what you want but you still end up with multiple setStates in a row (one per conflict). Try some more functionally-oriented approach, first calculate all the new conflicting classes, and only then add them to state:

```
newElementsValidatorHandler = () => {
  const newConflictingClasses = this.state.existingElements.filter(existingElement => existingElementIncludesNewFraction(existingElement))
  this.setState(({ conflictingClasses }) => ({
    conflictingClasses: [...conflictingClasses, newConflictingClasses]
  }))
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing the misuse of ```map``` and sharing your knowledge with me. I am still learning and its crucial to keep these fundamentals in mind so I don't get my code into the wrong direction.

Comment: in this case, according to the edition of my question, as I did not realize that I had not been clear before, your solution will abort at the first conflicting data, adding to the ```state``` just the first ```object``` found, as it will abort the loop. I actually would like to have this behaviour so ```state``` does not get set several times for each ```object```, but I actually want it to just ```setState``` once for each conflicting ```object``` inside the ```this.state.existingElements```. Take a look at my edition and the changes I've made on sandbox

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to `break` out of `map`, `some`, `forEach` so I created a custom class instead.

```
class BreakableLoopingArray {

  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data
  }

  forEach(callback) {

    // Create a flag to determine whether loop should proceed
    let shouldStop = false

    // A setter function to modify the flag
    const breakLoop = () => { shouldStop = true }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length && !shouldStop; i++) {
      callback({
        item: this.data[i],
        index: i,
        self: this.data,
        breakLoop,
      })
    }
  }

}
```

Then

```
newElementsValidatorHandler = () => {

  // Reset conflicting classes
  this.setState({ conflictingClasses: [] })

  const existingElements = new BreakableLoopingArray(this.state.existingElements)
  existingElements.forEach(({ item: existingElement, breakLoop: break1 }) => {

    const newElements = new BreakableLoopingArray(this.state.newElements)
    newElements.forEach(({ item: newElement, breakLoop: break2 }) => {

      const newFractions = new BreakableLoopingArray(newElement.elapse)
      newFractions.forEach(({ item: newFraction, breakLoop: break3 }) => {

        if (existingElement.elapse.includes(newFraction)) {
          this.setState(({ conflictingClasses, ...restTop }) => ({
            conflictingClasses: [...conflictingClasses, existingElement],
            ...restTop
          }));
          break1(); break2(); break3()
        }

      })

    })

  })

};
```

Below is another way to break out of those loops by creating a custom exception, but it's gonna complicate the code especially when you have deep nesting. (Just extra knowledge )

```
const arr = [
  { shouldStop: false },
  { shouldStop: false },
  { shouldStop: true },
  { shouldStop: false },
]

// Create a custom exception
class BreakException extends Error { }

try {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.shouldStop) {
      throw new BreakException()
    } else {
      console.log('Looping...')
    }
  })
} catch (e) {
  // If you do get an error and it's not a break exception, 
  if (e instanceof BreakException) {
    console.log('I broke out of the loop')
  } else {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

// Output:
// Looping...
// Looping...
// I broke out of the loop
```

Comment: @Alioshr Sorry that I delete this answer a moment ago. I re-read your question and figured that my solution does not align close enough to the problem so I removed it before I could come up with a better one.

Comment: No problem at all! I thank you for taking some time in order to teach me somethinh new. What the heck!!! I have just looked into this and my brain became a banana split for about 30 seconds haha. Very interesting! I'm gonna play with this a bit at codepen and i'll get back to you soon! Very interesting, as you still use ```forEach```

Comment: You are a Genius !!! This is an approach that I would never have imagined or seen before. I knew about using the regular ```for``` approach, but I wanted to use higher order methods, or something new, and this is really interesting (O_o)

Comment: wow excuse me, this is absurd. Creating custom class to wrap array just to "break out of forEach"? You are not even breaking out of it, you are creating your own method that is just called the same as forEach. Instances of this class are not arrays, don't have array methods, are not serializable and not usable in React. Nobody uses this kind of things in real world applications. It is not a good answer to give to a person with question about javascript basics

Comment: @Max Don't get me wrong, this is just a class and just one of the approaches towards the problem, not a replacement for the built-in `Array` class. More methods can be added to the custom class if needed or we can just append this method to the `Array.prototype`. Or, we can call `BreakableLoopingArray.data` to access the actual array itself.

Comment: @Max, I have eddited my state in order to better exemplify my question. On all the answers received the result will stop upon the first existing element in ```this.state. existingElements```. Now I have added another instance to the array of objects to make it clear that the iteration should ```set state``` just once per existing element. My own answer below still gets the desired result, but I think that it is not optimal.

Comment: @chin98edwin could you please take a look at my previous comment whenever you have a chance? I have added another instance into ```existingElements``` so it makes it clear that ```setState``` should occur once per ```existingElement```, and not just stop and return the first ```existingElement``` that has conflicting data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I said, I could filter the `oldState`

**(According to the edition to this question)**

Is anything more efficient that I could do here? As what I really want is to jump out of the loop, setting `state` once per conflicting object in `this.state.existingElements`

```
conflictingClasses: [
                ...conflictingClasses.filter(
                  prevClasses => prevClasses !== existingElement
                ),
                existingElement
              ],
```

Whole deal:

```
 newElementsValidatorHandler = () => {
    this.state.existingElements.forEach(existingElement => {
      return this.state.newElements.forEach(newElement =>
        newElement.elapse.some(newFraction => {
          if (existingElement.elapse.includes(newFraction)) {
            this.setState(({ conflictingClasses, ...restTop }) => ({
              conflictingClasses: [
                ...conflictingClasses.filter(
                  prevClasses => prevClasses !== existingElement
                ),
                existingElement
              ],
              ...restTop
            }));
          }
        })
      );
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array iterators that stop on the first miss like **findIndex**, **includes**, and **some**, you can break the code execution when a conflict occurs.

```js
const existingElements = [
  { id: 1, elapse: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  { id: 2, elapse: [5, 6, 7, 8] },
];

const newElements = [
  { id: 3, elapse: [9, 10, 7, 8] },
  { id: 4, elapse: [13, 14, 15, 99] },
];

// const intersects = (a, b) =>
//    a.findIndex(el => b.includes(el)) != -1
const intersects = (a, b) => {
  const result = a.findIndex(el => b.includes(el)) != -1;
  console.log('checking: ', a, b, 'result', result);

  return result;
};

existingElements.some(exEl =>
  newElements.some(newEl => intersects(exEl.elapse, newEl.elapse)),
);
```